# Django forms choicefield automatically generated choices

Tags: django, forms, choicefield

I have a form (forms.Form) that automatically generates the choices for its own choicefield as such:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    def generate_choices():
        from vn.account.models import UserProfile
        up = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
        choices = [('0','--')]
        choices += ([(s.id ,'%s %s (%s), username: %s, email: %s' % (s.first_name, s.last_name, s.company_name, s.username, s.email)) for s in up])
        return choices

    user = forms.ChoiceField(label=_('Select from interest form'), choices=generate_choices())
```

My problem is that this shows up as a select box (as intented) but its contents are cached somehow. New entries do not show up before i restart the dev server on my local pc, or apache on the remote server.

When is that piece of code evaluated? How can i make it so that it re-calculates the entries *every time* ?

PS. memchached and other sorts of caching are turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do this via the init so it is evaluate when form is called, something like

e.g.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    from vn.account.models import UserProfile
    up = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
    choices = [('0','--')]
    choices += ([(s.id ,'%s %s (%s), username: %s, email: %s' % (s.first_name, s.last_name,s.company_name, s.username, s.email)) for s in up])

    self.fields['user'].choices = choices
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is available starting from version 1.8: Django's ChoiceField has [ability to pass a callable to choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

> Either an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) of 2-tuples to use as
>   choices for this field, or a callable that returns such an iterable.
>   If the argument is a callable, it is evaluated each
>   time the field’s form is initialized.

So now you can just write

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    def generate_choices():
        from vn.account.models import UserProfile
        up = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
        choices = [('0','--')]
        choices += ([(s.id ,'%s %s (%s), username: %s, email: %s' % (s.first_name, s.last_name, s.company_name, s.username, s.email)) for s in up])
        return choices

    user = forms.ChoiceField(label=_('Select from interest form'), choices=generate_choices)
```

Also you can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) for this task.